# Plastic SCM with git in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, plasticscm

I've my repository in bitbucket, I use source control GIT.
I want, if it's posible, use Plastic SCM like client to my repository.
How can I do this?

Comment: You read http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2012/04/using-plastic-scm-as-github-client.html ?

Comment: You should check this one: http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2012/10/direct-pushpull-from-plastic-scm-to-git.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I do not work for Códice

Hi!

Right now, you can use the current method described by honk.

Códice is releasing an alpha version of 4.2 which one of the main new features (if not the main) is exactly this!

I'm using at home and it's pretty usable!
If you're interested in using this to try it out, you can send an email the Códice's support and I think they will be happy to send you a link to download the 4.2 version! :)

There are some well-known issues, but I think that they will be glad to explain to you which issues the current release have and I think you'll be happy using it! :)

One of the developers told me they're already using the 4.2 version for about 5 months inside Códice! Just today they release a new version of the 4.2 correcting some issues and bringing new features!

Answer (score 1):

I do recommend you to write to support (support at codicesoftware dot com) and give a try to the new Git bisync feature, it's still a beta so if you have feedback this is the place: https://plasticscm.uservoice.com/forums/181648-git-bisync

Answer (score 0):

I am using PlasticSCM vaersion 5.0.44.549 and I can directly Sync a branch with a bitbucket git repo or github for that matter.

In Plastic right click on a branch select Replication->Sync with Git...

In the dialog enter the git repo url your username and password and press the Sync button.

You get the best of bitbucket/github, the best DVCS and GUI out there with Plasticscm.